# How can I make the web server at our college show my resume instead of the list of files on the server?

Tags: httpserver

In my college we have a FTP server. I uploaded files to my account and they are listed on the website, but I want it to show my resume above the file list.

My profile is http://profile.iiita.ac.in/IEC2013011/. I would like it to look like  http://profile.iiita.ac.in/IEC2013089/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming your `resume.html` to `index.html` should work.

Comment: You might be able to create a `.htaccess` file and add `HeaderName resume.html` to it to show the resume above the file list, but I would recommend putting your personal files in a sub-directory, so they won't be visible to anyone visiting your website.